# Como mostrar un resultado en HTML

Tags: html, html5, fieldset

Tengo este codigo de html que creo que está perfecto, pero no consigo que al darle a `calcular` ejecute la operación y muestre el resultado en la casilla.

He comparado el código con otro que tengo que sí funciona perfecto y da el resultado y lo he visto  muchísimas veces y lo veo igual, no se si es que hay alguna variable que identifique mal o que el botón de calcular hace la operación pero no la muestra porque no esta conectado.

Usé https://www.onlinehtmleditor.net/ para editar el código mientras veía el resultado.ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>TESTAR OPERAÇOES</title>
  <style>
    div {
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 400px;
      background: #CF1EC7;
      border: 10px ridge red;
      padding: 10px;
      height: 250px
    }
    
    h2 {
      color: ;
      font-size: 30px;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    #botoes {
      height: 63px;
    }
    
    label {
      width: 190px;
      display: inline-block;
      float: right;
      padding: 0px 0 0px 0px;
    }
    
    p span {
      color: blue;
      font-family: Times2, arial;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 13px;
    }
    
    p {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    input[type=number] {
      padding: 2px;
      width: 62px;
    }
    
    input[type="text" i] {
      padding: 1px 2px;
      width: 62px;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    var a, b, x, listagem;

    function op() {

      a = document.getElementById("a").value;
      b = document.getElementById("b").value;
      x = document.getElementById("x").value;

      switch (x) {
        case "m":
          listagem = Math.min(a, b);
          break;
        case "M":
          listagem = Math.max(a, b);
          break;
        case "E":
          alert("ERROR");
          break;
        case "+":
          listagem = (a + b);
          break;
        case "-":
          listagem = (a - b);
          break;
        case "x":
          listagem = (a * b);
          break;
        case "/":
          listagem = (a / b);
          break;
        default:
          listagem = "Opção escolhida e invalida"
          break;
          document.getElementById("resultado").value = listagem;

      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h2>Testar Operações</h2>

    <form>
      <fieldset id="botoes">
        <label for="a"></label>
        <input type="number" id="a" placeholder="valor 1" /></br>
        <label for="x"></label>
        <input type="text" id="x" placeholder="operaçao?" /></br>
        <label for="b"></label>
        <input type="number" id="b" placeholder="valor 2" /></br>
      </fieldset>
      </br>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Cálculos/Limpar</legend>
        <input type="button" class="button" value="Calcular" onclick="op();" />
        <input type="reset" class="button" value="limpar dados" onclick="limpar();" />
        <input type="text" id="resultado" placeholder="resultado" disabled /> </br>

      </fieldset>

    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Tu error simplemente está en donde cierras el switch, tienes que cerrarlo antes de hacer

`document.getElementById("resultado").value = listagem;`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TESTAR OPERAÇOES</title>
        <style> 
            div {
              margin: 0 auto;
              width:400px;
              background: #CF1EC7;
              border: 10px ridge red;
              padding: 10px;
              height:250px
            }
            
            h2 {
              font-size: 30px;
              text-align:center;
            }
            
            #botoes {
              height: 63px;
            }
            
            label {
              width:190px;
              display:inline-block;
              float:right;
              padding: 0px 0 0px 0px;
            }
            
            p span {
              color:blue;
              font-family: Times2, arial;
              font-weight: bold;
              font-size: 13px;
            }
            
            p {
              text-align: center;
            }
            
            input[type=number] {
              padding: 2px;
              width: 62px;
            }
            
            input[type="text" i] {
              padding: 1px 2px;
              width: 62px;
            }
            
        
        </style>
        <script>
          var a, b, x, listagem;

          function op() {
            a = document.getElementById("a").value;
            b = document.getElementById("b").value;
            x = document.getElementById("x").value;
            a = parseInt(a);
            b = parseInt(b);
            console.log(a,b,x);
            switch(x){
              case "m":
                listagem = Math.min( a, b);
                break;
              case "M":
                listagem = Math.max( a, b);
                break;
              case "E":
                alert("ERROR");
                break;
              case "+":
                listagem = (a + b);
                break;
              case "-":
                listagem = (a - b);
                break;
              case "x":
                listagem = (a * b);
                break;
              case "/":
                listagem = (a / b);
                break;
              default:
                listagem = "Opção escolhida e invalida"
                break;
            }
            document.getElementById("resultado").value = listagem;
          }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <h2>Testar Operações</h2>
            
            <form>
                <fieldset id="botoes" >
                    <label for="a" ></label>
                    <input type="number" id="a" placeholder="valor 1"/></br>
                    <label for="x" ></label>
                    <input type="text" id="x" placeholder="operaçao?"/></br>
                    <label for="b" ></label>
                    <input type="number" id="b" placeholder="valor 2"/></br>    
                </fieldset>
                </br>
                <fieldset >
                    <legend>Cálculos/Limpar</legend>
                    <input type="button" class="button" value="Calcular"onclick="op();" />
                    <input type="reset" class="button" value="limpar dados" />
                    <input type="text"  id="resultado" placeholder="resultado"disabled /> </br>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A propósito, nunca te va hacer la suma bien, simplemente te va a concatenar los números, porque al hacer un ```a = document.getElementById("a").value;``` es un string. Para que sume deberías pasarlo a int

Comment: Como hago eso? :( y enserio muchisimas gracias no puedo creer que algo tanto tonto me comio la cabeza durante 2 horas.

Comment: Te acabo de corregir el ejemplo de código, para que veas como pasarlo a Int

Comment: enserio muchisimas gracias, llevaba horas y no sabia que era, graxx